# Add searchfield with recursive search to subpanel (similar to fixed searchfield with navbar)

Tags: mmenu

I'm using the most recent version of mmenu and playing around with the search.
When adding a searchfield with navbars to the top of the menu, I am getting a great global, recursive search through all panels and subpanels.

However, I want the search to be only available for one of the submenus and not all of them. On the top level we have e.g. "catalogue, imprint, contact, terms&conditions, etc" and I only want the search to appear in the catalogue submenu which has lots of more submenus.

However, when adding a searchfield to the panel with the catalogue, it will not search any of the submenus anymore.

Apparently, the "showSubPanels" option does not work in this context. Any other suggestions how to get a recursive search like the one in the navbar on one of the subpanels (and only there)?

Thank you,
Roland